# Laravel migrations table not found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, database-migration

I'm trying to recover a project after a failed HDD. Lost the mysql information, so just have the project code.

I hoped to be able to put my database back together by using `artisan migrate`, but the error message tells me:

```
database.migrations doesn't exist
```

Is there actually a way I can use my Laravel code files and the command line to rebuilt my database like this?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm assuming you update your app/config/database.php file with the correct info?

Comment: Yes. I've sorted it out now. I'll add the answer.

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The command I needed to run was:

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

(I actually had more problems than this because the mysql install was messed up to. I don't know if simply `php artisan migrate` on its own would have implied :install but I'm adding it as an answer anyway should anyone have similar issues)

Comment: I know this was necessary in laravel 3, but I think in laravel 4 it will do this for you when you run artisan migrate.

Comment: to run this for a specific database using `php artisan migrate:install database=database` did not work and I needed this for two databases besides the main database..

Comment: Great! Work for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue I had is that I would try to do `php artisan migrate:install`
which did create the table, however as soon as I did the `php artisan migrate` without the install, it would drop the empty migration table and would be unable to create or move it up. To move past the impasse, I `php artisan migrate --pretend` to get the first table's create table SQL, then I then added the first migration manually: `insert into migrations( migration, batch ) values ('2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table','1');` and then confirmed with `php artisan migrate:status` which showed that the first migration was successful.

```html
$ php artisan migrate:status

  Migration name .................................................................................................................... Batch / Status
  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table ..................................................................................................... [1] Ran
  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_reset_tokens_table ..................................................................................... Pending
  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table ............................................................................................... Pending
  2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table .................................................................................... Pending
```

Then the normal migration will succeed!